# Lenovo A916 Power Manager App Fails

Tags: applications, 4.4-kitkat, custom-roms, lenovo

I can't turn on emergency mode in **Lenovo Power Manager** app, it seams broken with my system.

Emergency Mode is like classic phone mode, only calls, SMS, contacts and clock are enabled. It saves energy.

### Problem

Whenever I try to activate it, it starts with `Preparing data, please wait...` and after that it says: `Failed to launch the Emergency Power Saving mode. Sorry, but we tried our best`

I've test this app on other Lenovo A916 with deferent ROM, it works there. Why is it not working with my ROM? Could someone help me find out why?

[image: screenshot]

### Logcat

I've made Logcat log, with hope that I will find cause of this problem and maybe fix it, but no luck. Maybe some experienced Android enthusiast will help me find out what causes the problem. Log file is kinda long but by searching `prepareEnvirenmentOperation` its easier to get entries

Logcat log is [here](http://pastebin.com/uFyWq9CH)

### Device information:

`Lenovo A916`, Android `4.4.2`, system build id `A916_S206_141125_baralajbi`

Comment: What device and Android version? What did you try already? Did it work before – and if so, what changes do you remember having done that might have effect here?

Comment: Android 4.4.2, I tried to enable it but this is what I get so far? Any idea?

Comment: No idea. I was hoping you'd name your device as well – so other users with the same device could help you out.

Comment: Improved question, maybe someone will take a look on that log. It bothers me.

Comment: Not sure, but what I notice from the logs: 1) your device is rooted, 2) you seem to have removed several packages (mainly fonts, but also some others like `com.android.mms` – but nothing that affects the powermanager), and finally 3) PowerManager seems not to like rooted devices, see e.g. lines 1282 to 1305: it starts up, checks for root (line 1299), finds root (1301+1302), and then seems to exit (1304ff). Some other process of the same app seems to continue, though, and do something. It probably won't show up due to all those "ResourceNotFound" errors, but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: @Izzy thank you for analyzing, :) maybe weird to say but ClassicPhoneLauncher requires root, if root is disabled PowerManager says that I need to root my phone to enable this function. I've notice those system.err messages, maybe system is missing something important? How to find out all missing package names?

Comment: Most of them are listed in those "unknown package" references I'd say. As for root: OK, that explains why the other thread still continues after that root check.

Comment: @Izzy problem solved, it was caused by SuperSU, I changed it and now it works. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem solved**, problem was caused by **SuperSU** root manager. After changing SuperSU to KingRoot it works fine. Weird.

I've tried different SuperSU settings, reboots, etc, but non of them seems to solve this issue. I got weirded out after trying this Lenovo app on my Alcatel tablet... it works perfectly fine there, with KingRoot, so I changed SuperSU to KingRoot on my Lenovo device and it works.